# Línea borde de pantalla en ionic popover

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic

Tengo un popover en ionic, que se activa al pulsar un `ion-button`. Al pulsarlo aparece el popover y funciona correctamente, pero en el borde de la pantalla aparece una línea.

Html donde se activa el popover:

```html
<ion-button class="ion-activatable ripple-parent ellipsis" slot="end" fill="clear" (click)="popover($event)" *ngIf="folder == 'Inicio' && this.fbs.email !== undefined">
   <ion-icon name="ellipsis-vertical-outline"></ion-icon>
   <ion-ripple-effect type="unbounded"></ion-ripple-effect>
</ion-button>
```

Método que activa el popover:

```js
async popover(ev: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverComponent,
      event: ev,
      animated: true,
      showBackdrop: true
    });
    return await popover.present();
  }
```

He probado a utilizar CSS, comprobar los estilos con el modo desarrollador pero no he conseguido dar con la clave. La [documentación](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover) no hace referencia a algo así.

A mi parecer, creo que se debe al focus que se le hace al popover, puesto que si el popover se queda abierto y pulso <kbd>tab</kbd> la línea desaparece y el popover sigue abierto.

Imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cómo comentabas será el focus lo que hace que se ponga ese borde. Por experiencias anteriores, no, no sé puede cambiar por estilos o al menos con atributos sin prioridad. Por estilos, intenta usar el !important.

```
border: 0px !important;
```

Comment: He estado investigando sobre el CSS de popover y con eso no ha sido suficiente para eliminar el borde. ¿Puede estar influyendo el ion-button?